# deleting unwanted columns from excel data frame

Tags: python-3.x

iam trying to read the excel sheet in python using pandas, i have most of the columns which are unnamed , and i wanted to delete those columns from data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import scipy
import scipy.stats as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics as st
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

rl = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\DELL\Krishna _ Reservoirs.xlsx",sheet_name="NAGARJUNASAGAR").drop(columns='Unnamed: 1')

rl.head()
```

Date    Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Storage in BCM  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Date.1  Unnamed: 9  Unnamed: 10 ... Unnamed: 142    Unnamed: 143    Date.18 Unnamed: 145    Unnamed: 146    Unnamed: 147    Storage in BCM.18   Unnamed: 149    Unnamed: 150    Unnamed: 151

0   1  January, 2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1  January, 2001    NaN NaN ... NaN NaN 1  January, 2018    NaN NaN NaN 1.735   NaN NaN NaN

1   2  January, 2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2  January, 2001    NaN NaN ... NaN NaN 2  January, 2018    NaN NaN NaN 1.682   NaN NaN NaN

2   3  January, 2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3  January, 2001    NaN NaN ... NaN NaN 3  January, 2018    NaN NaN NaN 1.634   NaN NaN NaN

3   4  January, 2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4  January, 2001    NaN NaN ... NaN NaN 4  January, 2018    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

4   5  January, 2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5  January, 2001    NaN NaN ... NaN NaN 5  January, 2018    NaN N

i cant write each time the code to drop Unnamed :  2, unnamed: 3,.....like this
so i need something such that all unnamed columns will be deleted and only date and storage in BCM columns should be there

Comment: table dumped... fix it OP. (From Review).

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are always only filled with `NaN` you could use `dropna`: [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Like

```
rl = rl.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

This will drop all columns in which all cells are `NaN`.